# How can I get a copy of my Codice Fiscale card if I am an expat?

Tags: united-kingdom, social-security, italian-citizens

I'm trying to get a copy of my Italian Codice Fiscale (Social Security number) card, but I live in the UK.

According to the [Italian Consulate](http://www.conslondra.esteri.it/Consolato_Londra/Menu/I_Servizi/Per_i_cittadini/Codice_Fiscale/Codice_Fiscale.htm), I need to ask any Agenzia delle Entrate, but according to the [Agenzia delle Entrate](http://www.agenziaentrate.gov.it/wps/content/Nsilib/Nsi/Home/CosaDeviFare/Richiedere/Codice+fiscale+e+tessera+sanitaria/Richiesta+TS_CF/SchedaI/Come+si+chiede+il+Codice+Fiscale/) I need to ask the Italian Consulate!

Before I follow these instructions and loop indefinitely, has anyone succeeded in this endeavor? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I emailed the Consulate General of Italy in London with a similar issue - the difference being I already had my paper version but I needed the plastic card version before I could open a bank account (they wouldn't accept the paper version during a webcam verification).  The response I received was:

"...I am sorry, but we  do not have this service, here.
However you can delegate somebody  who lives in Italy  to accept the plastic card on you behalf..."

Classic 'chicken and egg' :)

Answer (score 1):

The consulate can only obtain you a copy of the number in mail, not the card. To get the card you need to follow the instructions here at [the consular web page](http://www.conslondra.esteri.it/Consolato_Londra/Menu/I_Servizi/Per_i_cittadini/Codice_Fiscale/)

Follow the second part of the instruction as the first part will only get you a mail with the number, not the plastic card.

You'll have to use [this form](http://www.agenziaentrate.gov.it/wps/file/Nsilib/Nsi/Home/CosaDeviFare/Richiedere/Codice+fiscale+e+tessera+sanitaria/Richiesta+TS_CF/Modello+e+istruzioni+CF+AA4_8/modello+cf+AA48/modello+AA4+8.pdf) and specify in section D your abroad address and you'll need to send it to any Agenzia delle Entrate office, not trough the consulate. Better if you send it to an office near someone you know that can go and check the status of the inquiry or deliver the form manually.

Comment: I linked to that page in my question. The Agenzia delle Entrate site says exactly the opposite. I am not quite sure what to do with that PDF form anyways, where to send it to.